# C# удаление, перезапись строки в текстовом файле

Tags: c#, строки, файлы

Имею следующий код:

```
string path = @"C:\ContractRN\RN_Contract.txt";
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path, System.Text.Encoding.Default))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        try
        {
            ProcessContract(line);
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException e)
        {
            Logger.Error($"Ошибка: {e.Message}");
            RecordingInFile.FailedReplaceForExeption(line, "Не смог обработать");
            RecordingInFile.RNContractForAllProcessing(line);
            Page.Open("http://pik-test19.informicus.ru/client/#!/contractExecution/contracts/FL44");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

что он делает, достает строку и файла и начинает ее обработку,
дело в том, что строк будет около 5 к, я бы хотел бы, чтобы после каждой итерации цикла `while` он удалял уже обработанную строку данных, потому что, если он упадет, то все будет обрабатывать заново, помогите, пожалуйста, желательно с примерами, заранее спасибо.

Comment: Да уберите `return` из `catch`, и не придётся заново всё обрабатывать.

Comment: да дело в том, что я бы хотел удалить строку именно в самом файле, return уберу, но он же все равно потом, если упадет полностью, начнем смотреть уже отработанные строки

Comment: Ну, управлять потоком исполнения через текстовый файл вообще не очень хорошо, лучше через записи в БД. Но если очень хочется - ну, тогда вам придётся на каждой итерации цикла в начале его открывать файл и читать одну строку, а в конце цикла копировать файл (за исключением первой строки). Что у вас вызывает затруднение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

5000 строк - это совсем мало. Если процесс обработки затягивается, то скорее всего у вас плохой код в методе обработки, и его нужно оптимизировать. Нет никакого смысла наворачивать костыли на этот процесс в виде полной перезаписи файла после обработки каждой строки, как минимум потому что это в десятки раз еще замедлит процесс. Запустил - обработал - почистил файл - всё. Здесь достаточно убрать `return`.

**Важно:** `Encoding.Default` - не надо так делать. На разных компах разная кодировка по умолчанию может быть. И обязательно случится так, что вы не сможете прочитать файл, записанный на другом компе. Испольльзуйте `StreamReader` без явного указания кодировки, тогда он будет читать в кодироке `UTF-8 без BOM` по умолчанию.

```
string path = @"C:\ContractRN\RN_Contract.txt";
using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenRead(path))
{
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        string line = sr.ReadLine();
        try
        {
            ProcessContract(line);
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException e)
        {
            Logger.Error($"Ошибка: {e.Message}");
            RecordingInFile.FailedReplaceForExeption(line, "Не смог обработать");
            RecordingInFile.RNContractForAllProcessing(line);
            Page.Open("http://pik-test19.informicus.ru/client/#!/contractExecution/contracts/FL44");
        }
    }
}
File.Move(path, path + ".backup"); // создание резервной копии, если требуется
File.WriteAllText(path, ""); // полная очистка файла
```

Либо, если вы хотите перезаписать файл, только за исключением "плохих" строк, то можно так

```
string path = @"C:\ContractRN\RN_Contract.txt";
string tmpPath = @"C:\ContractRN\RN_Contract.txt.tmp";
using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenRead(path))
using (StreamWriter sw = File.Create(tmpPath))
{
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        string line = sr.ReadLine();
        try
        {
            ProcessContract(line);
            sw.WriteLine(line);
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException e)
        {
            Logger.Error($"Ошибка: {e.Message}");
            RecordingInFile.FailedReplaceForExeption(line, "Не смог обработать");
            RecordingInFile.RNContractForAllProcessing(line);
            Page.Open("http://pik-test19.informicus.ru/client/#!/contractExecution/contracts/FL44");
        }
    }
}
File.Delete(path);
File.Move(tmpPath, path);
```

Только не забудьте реализовать качественную обработку ошибок, чтобы не терять данные, если что-то пойдет не так. Например файл не откроется или возникнет ошибка при доступе к диску во время выполнения метода.

Comment: Благодарю за развернутый ответ!