# c# Удаление строк при чтение файла txt

Tags: c#, файлы, txt

подскажите как можно при чтение текстового файла удалять прочитанные строки. Про варианты считать файл в память и перезаписать в курсе, пожалуйста не предлагать.

Comment: И в чем проблема?

Comment: Файл можно читать или дописывать в конец файла, но нельзя из него что то удалять, удаление решается только перезаписью. Поглядите метода класса Stream, там нет удаления, только чтение и запись.

Comment: @tym32167 читайте вопрос внимательнее, там написано было что такие варианты не предлагать

Comment: А что предлагать то? Базу данных используйте, если вам надо что-то удалять без перезаписывания в файл. Файл - это не база данных, физически это просто последовательный поток байт, можно встать на определенный байт и с него начать читать, или с него начать писать, больше ничего делать с файлом нельзя. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1250068/373567

Comment: Ну и здесь не рынок, чтобы выбирать, что вам будут предлагать, а что не будут. Рассмотрели уже вариант с перезаписью? Это хорошо, потому что других вариантов удалять что то из файла нет.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с перезаписью... Вы в курсе, что для того, что бы **увидеть** содержимое файла, его нужно открыть? А для того, что бы его открыть, вам нужно его закинуть себе в **оперативную память**. Т.к. у вас не получится что-то удалить или что-то записать, или просто отобразить информацию не считывая её из файла.

Если вы хотите что-то оттуда **удалить**, то вам придется неким образом обновить ту информацию, которую вы уже закинули себе в ОЗУ (Считали данные из файла), т.е. удалить какие-то строки кодом. Как вы будете понимать, какие удалять, а какие нет - это ваша задача.

Если вам важно прям **удаление** некого содержимого, можете **считать** всё в List<> а потом использовать метод .Remove()

А для того, что бы вам сохранить ту информацию, которую вы неким образом обновили или обработали, вам нужно будет куда-то её **записать**.

Answer (score 0):

Есть вариант сделать файл постоянного размера и циклически его перезаписывать. Файл состоит из записей постоянного размера, рассчитанного на самую длинную строку. В этом случае ничего удалять не нужно. Использовать два указателя - на последнюю записанную строку и на последнюю прочитанную.

Немного усложнив алгоритм, можно предусмотреть возможность увеличения размера файла, а так же разбивку строки на несколько записей.

Если жалко места, то можно отдельно индекс сделать.